# Does the Global Catalog Server have to be in the same subnet as the Exchange server?

Tags: exchange-2003, windows-2000

I have one domain.  I have a DC in one subnet and an Exchange 2003 in another.  I also have a DC in that same subnet as the Exchange 2003 server.  I have to get rid of that DC, the one in the same subnet as the Exchange server.  That will leave me with one DC in one subnet and Exchange in another.

Will Exchange 2003 work?

Windows 2000 domain.  Yes I'm upgrading it...slowly.

Answer (score 3):

Is it required? No. It is recommended, however, to have the Global Catalog in the same site.

I would not recommend running with only one domain controller in your domain. Beyond just the fact that this is a single point of failure for your entire domain infrastructure, depending on how many users you have, you could also experience performance issues running on a single DC.

You can have a look at [Microsoft's own recommendations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124454(v=exchg.65).aspx) on DC/GC placement with Exchange 2000/2003.

> Because Exchange uses Active Directory, it is crucial that you
>   consider your Windows Server network topology as you plan your
>   Exchange deployment. In general, for best performance, you should make
>   sure you have at least one global catalog server in each Windows site
>   where Exchange is installed

Comment: I have two DCs.  I'm just getting rid of one of them.  The other is Global Catalog DC but it is in another subnet, same domain though, so I wasn't sure.

Comment: My point is that I wouldn't get rid of one of them and keep two DC's in your environment running at any given time.